# Get composer doctrine package without it's dependency

Tags: laravel, doctrine-orm

I would like to know if it's a correct to get just one package like "doctrine/dbal": "^2.7" and not it's dependencies like doctrine/annotations, doctrine/cache, doctrine/collections, doctrine/common, etc.

Thanks for your answers :)
Christophe

Comment: In general, dependencies are loaded because the base package requires them to operate.  dbal definitely needs the common and collections and cache packages.    It might work without annotations but it hardly seems worth the effort to remove it.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) Well we are using Laravel with dbal, but not the other packages, so i try to know if we can just install dbal and not the others but with your answer it seem to be a bad idea

Comment: I guess the point is that if you are using the dbal then you are using the other dependencies.  Maybe not directly but the dbal is.  If you wanted to experiment then just delete them from the vendor directory and see what sort of errors you get.  Probably lots of "class not found" exceptions.